# What would be a good way to communicate between components and services in Angular

Tags: angular6

I am looking for best practices in `Angular` to communicate between a `UI` `component` and an `Angular` Service.

My UI has a `status bar component`. It has a `signin` button. When user signs in, the `username` and `password` are sent from the `status bar component` to a `angular service`. The `angular service` then uses `http.post` method to send the request to the server. The `angular service` handles the response from the server and then emits an `Observable` of its own which contains the outcome of login request. The `status bar component` subscribes to the `observable` of the `angular service` (at `ngOnInit`) and depending on the result value, it either pops an error message or replaces the `login button` with `welcome ...` message.  Is this the right way of communicating between `components` and `services` in `Angular` or is there a better design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a perfectly valid use case of services in a component, this type of service usage is called [dependency injection](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services).

One thing that should be known are "stores", such as [Redux, RxJs or Ngrx Store.](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-redux-ngrx-rxjs/).
Stores can be useful when the application is split up in lots of different component that may be sharing the same data.

In these cases there can be some difficulties keeping all the components data in the same "state". Stores is a good way to keep the shared data in sync